# Print the input without using char array

Tags: c

Is it possible to print the input that the user entered without using a char array?

This code doesn't work when the Enter character is involved:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{    
    int ch;
    while((ch = getchar()) != EOF){
          putchar(ch);
    } 
}
```

For example, I want to enter:

```
abcd
efgh
ij
```

and I want the output to be the same:

```
abcd
efgh
ij
```

but when I enter the first line, the program should also output that line (after my Enter). and it's like this:

```
abcd (my input)
abcd (output)
efgh (my input)
efgh (output)
ij   (my input)
ij   (output)
```

Comment: Not possible to get the expected output with your given condition!

Comment: as haccks said, you must rethink your algorithm

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements? When you say 'enter three lines of input', you mean that you run your program and type the three lines at the standard input? And you want your program to echo the data, but: do you want to see just one copy of the data, or do you want to see two copies of the data, one before the other, or do you want to see interleaved input and output lines? What do you want to happen if the input is redirected from a file instead of typed from a keyboard? Are you on a Unix-like machine, or on Windows, or something else (because some of suggestions might need POSIX)?

Comment: you could `malloc` some space, technically that's not a char array

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fp = fopen("echo.tmp", "w+");
    int ch;
    while((ch = getchar()) != EOF){
        fputc(ch, fp);
    }
    fflush(fp);
    rewind(fp);
    while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
        putchar(ch);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    remove("echo.tmp");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For fun, an impracticable recursive solution.

After reading a `char`, put it on the stack and recurse.

When done (EOF), recurse through the stack.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct prev_T {
  struct prev_T *prev;
  int ch;
} prev_T;

void put1(prev_T *s) {
  if (s != NULL) {
    // Swap this line and the next if you want to print in reverse.
    put1(s->prev);
    putc(s->ch, stdout);
  }
}

void get1(prev_T *s) {
  prev_T node;
  node.ch = getchar();
  if (node.ch == EOF) {
    put1(s);
  } else {
    node.prev = s;
    get1(&node);
  }
}

  int main(void) {
    get1(NULL);
    return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

An even more impractical recursive solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void unwind(va_list ap)
{
    int ch = va_arg(ap, int);
    if ( ch == EOF )
        return;

    va_list a2 = va_arg(ap, va_list);
    va_end(ap);
    unwind(a2);
    putchar(ch);
}

void package(int dummy, ... )
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, dummy);

    int ch = getchar();
    if ( ch == EOF )
        unwind(ap);
    else
        package(0, ch, ap);
}

int main()
{
    package(0, EOF);
}
```

Comment: You could even make `dummy` be some sort of input parameter, e.g. a maximum length

Answer (score 0):

The simple, non-recursive, very practical method to accomplish your intended output from the input you give is to read individual characters and output them immediately, with special handling for special characters.  For instance, you might test for character value 13 to output a newline character when the enter key is pressed, and look for some other special character to signal end of input.